# java concurrency in practice 16.1

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In this code:

```
public class PossibleReordering {
    static int x = 0, y = 0;
    static int a = 0, b = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InterruptedException {
        Thread one = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                a = 1;
                x = b;
            }
        });
        Thread other = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                b = 1;
                y = a;
            }
        });
        one.start(); other.start();
        one.join();   other.join();
        System.out.println("( "+ x + "," + y + ")");
    }
}
```

They say Java Compiler will reorder the instructions in thread one and thread other to optimize its execution, and finally cause the result (0,0).

And also they say:
Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program order.

Does those two statement conflict with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The happens-before rule only applies to statements that depend on each other. Since these `run()` methods both contain assignments that are independent, the compiler is allowed to reorder them, which may cause the output you describe.
You can read the definition of `happens-before` in the Javaspecs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> *It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take
>   place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces
>   results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal.*

For example, if the first `run()` method looked like this:

```
public void run() {
    b = 1;
    x = b;
}
```

no reordering would be permitted.